# KENDO line chart error bars show /hide on hover

Tags: javascript, charts, kendo-ui, line

http://dojo.telerik.com/aGisuSuR/2

I am trying to hide and show error bar on a Kendo line chart based on when the mouse is over the line point, is it possible to do this? I tried using highlight, I can probably create a visual, but I just wanted to hide all the error bars and show only when the point is highlighted. I tried to set erroBar visibility false and set it to true on Highlight, that doesn't seem to work. Even if this worked, this would set the visibility of all error bars, I just want to set it for only one point at a time, as showing all at once is will overlap error bars.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/remote-data-binding">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function createChart() {
           var StrokeAnimation = kendo.drawing.Animation.extend({
             init: function(element) {
               kendo.drawing.Animation.fn.init.call(this);
               this.initialStroke = $.extend({}, element.options.stroke);
               this.color = element.options.fill.color;
               this.element = element;
              
             },
             step: function(pos) {
               this.element.stroke(this.color, this.initialStroke.width * pos * 5, 0.5);
             },
             
             reset: function() {
               this.element.options.set("stroke", this.initialStroke);
             }
           });
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                dataSource: [
    {
        "country": "Spain",
        "year": "2008",
        "unit": "GWh",
        "solar": 2578,
        "hydro": 26112,
        "wind": 32203,
        "nuclear": 58973,
    "low":51000,
    "high":68000
    },
    {
        "country": "Spain",
        "year": "2007",
        "unit": "GWh",
        "solar": 508,
        "hydro": 30522,
        "wind": 27568,
        "nuclear": 55103,
     "low":52000,
    "high":60000
    },
    
],
                title: {
                    text: "Spain electricity production (GWh)"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "top"
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "line",
                    errorLowField: "low",
                    errorHighField: "high",
                    errorBars: {
                      highlight:{
                      line: {
                        width: 1,
                        dashType: "solid"
                       }
                      },
                    
                    visible: true,
                    endCaps: true,
                    width: 10,
                    color: "darkblue",
                    line: {
                        width: 1,
                        dashType: "solid"
                       }
                   },
                    highlight: {
                      errorBars: {
                        line: {
                          width: 1,
                          dashType: "solid"
                         }
                      }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    field: "nuclear",
                    name: "Nuclear"
                }, {
                    field: "hydro",
                    name: "Hydro"
                }, {
                    field: "wind",
                    name: "Wind"
                }],
                categoryAxis: {
                    field: "year",
                    labels: {
                        rotation: -90
                    },
                    crosshair: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        format: "N0"
                    },
                    majorUnit: 10000
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: false,
                    shared: false,
                    format: "N0"
                },
               
               render: function(e) {
                
                }
              
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
    </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to draw the error bars yourself on the seriesOver event and seriesLeave event.

First, clear previously drawn lines. Check you are over a circle object (the marker) then get its x-position. From the hovered point, get the error high and low values from the dataItem and convert to coordinates using the axis.slot(). Finally draw the lines.  In my example, I am clearing the lines on seriesLeave after a five second timeout.

**[DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/eBALUlaZ)**

```
var timeout;
```

...

```
seriesOver: function(e) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);                
  $('[opacity="0.9999998"]').remove();
            
  if (e.element.tagName == "circle") {
    var xVal = e.element.cx.baseVal.value;
    var chart = e.sender;
    var yAxis = chart.getAxis("value");
    var valSlot = yAxis.slot(e.dataItem.low, e.dataItem.high);
            
    var strokeColor = "#535D5D";
    var strokeWidth = 2;
    var uniqueOpacity = 0.9999998; //for removing previously drawn
    //vertical error bar
    var path = new kendo.drawing.Path({
      stroke: {color: strokeColor, width: strokeWidth}
    }).moveTo(e.element.cx.baseVal.value , valSlot.origin.y)
    .lineTo(e.element.cx.baseVal.value, valSlot.origin.y + valSlot.size.height)
    .opacity(uniqueOpacity);
    //end cap 1
    var pathEnd1 = new kendo.drawing.Path({
      stroke: {color: strokeColor, width: strokeWidth}
    }).moveTo(e.element.cx.baseVal.value - 4 , valSlot.origin.y)
    .lineTo(e.element.cx.baseVal.value + 4, valSlot.origin.y)
    .opacity(uniqueOpacity);
    //end cap 2
    var pathEnd2 = new kendo.drawing.Path({
      stroke: {color: strokeColor, width: strokeWidth}
    }).moveTo(e.element.cx.baseVal.value - 4 , valSlot.origin.y + valSlot.size.height)
    .lineTo(e.element.cx.baseVal.value + 4, valSlot.origin.y + valSlot.size.height)
    .opacity(uniqueOpacity);
    //Draw on chart
    chart.surface.draw(path);
    chart.surface.draw(pathEnd1);
    chart.surface.draw(pathEnd2);                    
  }                
 },
 seriesLeave: function(e) {
   setTimeout(function(){
     $('[opacity="0.9999998"]').remove();
   }, 5000);                
 }
```